# Finding special limit Euler Method for e(1)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to prove that $(e - (1+h)^{1/h})/h$ approaches $e/2$ for $h$ close to zero. Any hints on how to show this? I have tried L'Hôpital with implicit differentiation but I end up nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

set
$$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix} e \\ \left( 1+x\right)^\frac{1}{x} \end{matrix}\right|\begin{matrix} \begin{align} \text{if } x=0 \end{align} \\  \text{else}  \end{matrix}$$
$f(x)$ is continues, so now:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e - (1+h)^{1/h}}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0) - f(0+h)}h=f'(0)$$

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\text{ }\left.\frac d{dx} \left( 1+x\right)^\frac{1}{x}\right\rvert_{x=h}$$

$$f(x)=\left( 1+x\right)^\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\ln f(x)=\left.\frac{\ln(1+x)}x\right/\frac{d}{dx}()$$

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln (1+x)}{x^2}$$

$$f'(x)=f(x) \cdot\frac{\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln (1+x)}{x^2}$$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e - (1+h)^{1/h}}h = \lim_{h\to0}f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0} f(h) \cdot\frac{\frac{h}{1+h}-\ln (1+h)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to0} e\cdot\frac{\frac{h}{1+h}-\ln (1+h)}{h^2}=e\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h-(h+1)\ln (1+h)}{h^3+h^2}=e\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-1-\ln (1+h)}{3h^2+2h}=-e\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\text{ }\frac{\ln (1+h)}{3h^2+2h}=-e\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\text{ }\frac{\frac1{1+h}}{6h+2}=-e\cdot\frac{\frac11}2=-\frac e2$$